# Как при работе Bottom Sheet заблокировать главный Activity?

Tags: android, android-bottomsheet

Я добавил себе в приложение Bottom Sheet с этого урока (https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/) но заметил, что если под Bottom Sheet находится кнопка или что-либо ещё что имеет onClick при нажатии на это место в Bottom Sheet, он будет выполняться, даже не смотря на то, что поднят Bottom Sheet. Как это можно устранить?

**Bottom sheet**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sliding_up"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="62dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Sophia Connors"
        android:textColor="#292929"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="(650) 555-1122"
        android:textColor="#292929"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#A3A3A3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sophiacon@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="#292929"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Personal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/main"/>
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_persistent"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Content Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/money_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_circle_day"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="startanim"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:transitionName="transition1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: попробуйте у bottomSheet установить android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"

Comment: fragment bottom sheet